# Web Service with https only certificate - 403 forbidden on Android

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, ssl, xamarin.android

I'm trying to connect my android application via https to my webservice and I keep getting

System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request: Status code 403(Forbidden): Forbidden

The webservice seems fine with the browser. I also installed the certificate in Android but I still get a warning by browser.

this is my method

```
public static string HttpSoap2()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding () {
        Name= "basicHttpBinding",
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 67108864,
    };

    binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() {
        MaxArrayLength = 2147483646,
        MaxStringContentLength = 5242880,
    };

    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
    binding.SendTimeout= timeout;
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

    Service1Client client;

    client = new Service1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));

    // This will allow us to ignore the validation of the server-side certificate while maintaining
    // transport encryption. 
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };

    return client.Greeting ("LOL");
}
```

and this is my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false        before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="MyHelloService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myBehaviour">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="https://10.XXX.XX.XX:443"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpsBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="myBinding" 
                contract="MyHelloService.IService1" />
      <endpoint address="Service1.svc/mex"
                binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>       
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

am I forgetting something?

**UPDATE** 
<del>looks like my certificate doesn't stay installed</del>
I've upload a pfx that i've exported from my selfsigned
then i've sent it to sdcard and tried to open browser and install it from sdcard
but i get this
 413.16 Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid

meanwhile i've already tried to change the service to use credentials to see if something would change. Everything stayed the same

Comment: Is your browser on the machine that runs the service? If so it could be a firewall or other security issue.

Comment: both emulator and pc browser are in the same pc. With emulator's browser I get that warning even after I've installed the certificate. With pc's browser everything seems fine. I've been wandering around this problem for days now

Comment: Try to verify that you can get to the IIS homepage in the emulator. That would rule out security issue at the machine level.

Comment: not sure if its this what you mean http://postimage.org/image/dqbuwultt/ this happens after even after i had the certificate installed. Upload it to dropbox then open it with browser and everything seems to went fine

Comment: I tried to upload the cert to sd card instead using dropbox. Got the same results... as soon I install the certificate its deleted from sdcard and if I go to security -> certificates , it doesnt show up anywere... its like it cant be installed. When I used the browser this time I got an error 403.16 Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid. What do i do next? the certificate works for the pc, why not for android?